# Dart 1.3.3 entry startup .html file

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I created a simple app with Dart 1.3.3 using the polymer option. The index.html is shown below

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Sample app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="zones.css">

<!-- import the click-counter -->
<link rel="import" href="clickcounter.html">
<script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Zones</h1>

<p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

<div id="sample_container_id">
  <click-counter count="5"></click-counter>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This file runs without any issue.

BUT then, after a while I start getting a cosole message that the startup as change and the following file should be used

```dart
... <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
```

and that I should use the following

```dart
 <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart;component=1" src="index.dart"></script>
```

etc, etc.

Should not the new generated application by Dart 1.3.3 create the file formatted in  the new format?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What Polymer version are you using?

DartEditor 1.3.3 came out a while ago I think.
When there was a newer Polymer release published after DartEditor 1.3.3 was released it probably doesn't create the new application with the new requirements.

The messages indicate that you are using a Polymer 0.10.0-dev.x version which only a pre-release.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. Could I have polluted my setup by some pub package I loaded. I am pretty sure I am using 1.3.3 stable release. I have deleted the file/folders .dartium, DartEditor and Pub all under the my windows user directory but the problems still persist. Are there any other files/folders that I need to delete so the cache can be removed. Polymer version is 0.9.5+2. Thanks

Comment: I believe you (Dart version) but what Polymer version are you using? You see it when you expand the packages folder in DartEditor (only the top-most packages folder in the package).

Comment: Polymer version is 0.9.5+2

Comment: Beats me. I'm sure these changes were introduced with 0.10.0-dev

Comment: Are you aware of any other folder/files I need to remove to get rid of Dart cache Gunter apart from .dartium, DartEditor and Pub all under the my windows user directory.

Comment: I don't know where Dart creates directories on Windows. On Linux I have the DartEditor installation dir and ~/.pub-cache.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51697/discussion-between-st-clair-clarke-and-gunter-zochbauer)

Comment: I have a meeting in a few minutes. Sorry, I probably won't have time today anymore.